# MQ java process taking 100% of CPU

Tags: ibm-mq

Following process in our linux server is taking 100% of CPU

```
java -DMQJMS_LOG_DIR=/opt/hd/ca/mars/tmp/logs/log -DMQJMS_TRACE_DIR=/opt/hd/ca/mars/tmp/logs/trace -DMQJMS_INSTALL_PATH=/opt/isv/mqm/java com.ibm.mq.jms.admin.JMSAdmin -v -cfg /opt/hd/ca/mars/mqm/data/JMSAdmin.config
```

I forcibly killed the process and bounced MQ then i don't see this. What might be the reason for this to happen?

Comment: Does it write a lot of tracing messages?

Answer (score 0):

The java process `com.ibm.mq.jms.admin.JMSAdmin` is normally executed via the IBM MQ script `/opt/mqm/java/bin/JMSAdmin`.

The purpose of JMSAdmin is to create JNDI resources for connecting to IBM MQ, these are normally file based and stored in a file called `.binding`, the location of the `.binding` file would be found in configuration file that is passed to the command.  In your output above the configuration file is `/opt/hd/ca/mars/mqm/data/JMSAdmin.config`.

JMSAdmin is an interactive process where you run commands such as:

```
DEFINE QCF(QueueConnectionFactory1) +
       QMANAGER(XYZ) +
       ...
```

---

I would be unable to tell you why it was taking 100% CPU, but the process itself does not directly interact with or connect to the queue manager and it would be safe to kill off the process with out needing to restart the queue manager.  The `.binding` file that `JMSAdmin` generates is used by JMS applications in some configurations to find details of how to connect to MQ and the names of queues and topics to access.

---

In July 2011 you would have been using IBM MQ v7.0 or lower all of which are out of support, if anyone should come across a similar issue with a recent supported version of MQ I would suggest you take a java thread dump and open a case with IBM to investigate why it is taking up 100% of the CPU.

---

*PS I know this is a 9 year old question, but I thought an answer may be helpful to someone who finds this when searching for a similar problem.